# How to set max integer value of input field by CSS?

Tags: css, validation, web, frontend

Can I set an max value for a number field without using JavaScript? Can I set this kind of 'validation' with pure CSS?
Thanks for help!

Comment: No, you can not, because such a limit is not “formatting” to begin with, it is _logic_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to use `:out of range` pseudo class on your CSS, like below

```
<style>
input:out-of-range{
   background: red;
   color:#fff;
}
</style>

<input type="number" min="0" max="50" value="55">
```

Answer (score 1):

:valid and :invalid CSS selectors can be used to indicate if form values are valid or not. But you will need HTML5 attributes like max/min or javascript to do validation.

HTML

```
<div class="form-control">
   <input type="text" required />
   <span class="bar"></span>
<label for="First Name">First Name</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input:valid ~ .bar:before, input:valid ~ .bar:after{
background:#2ecc71;  
}

input:invalid ~ .bar:before, input:invalid ~ .bar:after{
 background:#e74c3c;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `max` attribute on `input` field.

```
<input type="number" max="20">
```

**P.S. -** It will restrict the value of `input` field to **maximum** 20. But will not restrict if the user types 21 or 211. That you need to handle using **JS**. And of course, `maxlength` does not work on `type"number"`